# Submit and Index page/url changes in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

I made some changes to a page and it's url, and have configured my web server to redirect from the old to the new. After fetching the old and new url's in the search console the results appear as redirected and complete, respectively. Should I submit and index both, or one or the other? Why?

Comment: If one redirects to the other, you do not have to do anything at all.

Comment: @closetnoc Is Submit and Index meant for new pages, and there is no benefit in doing any of the above?

Comment: You can use this option anytime. Unless the page is new and very timely, I do not recommend that people try and hurry Google up. These features will disappear if abused. Already, this feature is no longer real-time as a result. The regular googlebot will come by in a day or two to make it official. Why? Because people abused this feature and p1$$3d Google off.

Comment: @closetnoc I didn't realize it was such a problem in the past and just figured the monthly submission limit they put in place would prevent people from abusing their system. My content for these changes isn't very timely so redirect should be good for whenever googlebot or whoever comes around I guess.

Comment: Kev- Can I call you that? One brother and a couple best friends growing up, it just feels natural. Generally speaking, if there is no timely need for a page to be indexed, I suggest to everyone that they let Google do it's thing. Google will figure out how fast it should visit a site and pages. Sitemaps can help this for larger sites. You can also signal important changes and updates with a link within the home page content. This is usually the best way to get attention to important (to you at least) updates. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Oh hey, sure you can call me Kev! And what should I call YOU, exactly? R.K?

Comment: Considering what some call me... anything is an improvement!!

Comment: With the exception of Steve, Stephanie, and Lilli, the rest of my brothers, sisters, and their/our kids are all K names. What up with us?? No imagination. Maybe we are just all Krazy.

Comment: @closetnoc Hmmm... doesn't sound familiar. Do you think we know each other?

Comment: Probably. My family really got around. Kan't swing a dead Kat without hitting Kin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37999/discussion-between-kevin-and-closetnoc).